# Port not open inside WCF service

Tags: .net, wcf, c++-cli, port, named-pipes

I have a named pipe WCF service. The service itself calls external DLL code that I have no authority over. Some parts of this code need to listen on specific HTTP ports (I can provide the IP and port used for the communication but that's all). Basically, it sets up a status monitor and expects status messages coming in on the port from a server of a hardware device.

When the code to be placed into the service runs in a separate, standalone program, it works all right, the incoming connection takes place. But when run inside a service, something blocks the access to this port. Not the firewall, that has been checked. I tried to get port access permission using:

```
auto perms = gcnew SocketPermission(NetworkAccess::Accept, TransportType::All, ip, port);
perms->Demand();
```

but it doesn't help. Analyzing the network traffic shows that the remote party tries to send packets repeatedly but the service doesn't see and accept them.

Some code (although I don't think it really adds to the context this time):

```
static void Main(array<String^>^ args) {
  array<ServiceBase^>^ ServicesToRun = gcnew array<ServiceBase^> { gcnew Service() };
  ServiceBase::Run(ServicesToRun);
}

virtual void OnStart(array<System::String^>^ args) override {
  Hosts->Clear();

  try {
    auto binding = gcnew NetNamedPipeBinding();
    binding->MaxReceivedMessageSize = Int32::MaxValue;
    binding->ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan::MaxValue;

    Hosts->Add(AddHost(Test::typeid, ITest::typeid, binding, "net.pipe://localhost/service/test"));
  }
  catch (Exception^ e) {
    Log::Debug(e);
  }
}

ServiceHost^ AddHost(Type^ serviceClass, Type^ interfaceClass, Binding^ binding, String^ address) {
  auto host = gcnew ServiceHost(serviceClass);
  host->AddServiceEndpoint(interfaceClass, binding, address);
  host->Open();
  return host;
}

public interface class ITest {
  [OperationContract] void TestMonitor();
};

void Test::TestMonitor() {
  auto perms = gcnew SocketPermission(NetworkAccess::Accept, TransportType::All, ip, port);
  perms->Demand();
  Log::Debug("OK so far");

  // This external function is supposed to register the callback function on a server
  // and send regular status reports to ip:port. It fails because the service
  // is not allowed to listen on the port.
  StartMonitor(ip, port, callback);
  Log::Debug("never reached, the previous line times out");
}
```

Comment: Did you set a breakpoint at your function call? You never told us how you actually call your WCF/NamedPipe Service. Do you at all? Do you get any error message from your function? An exception maybe?

Comment: It times out, no exception. Network analysis shows that it simply doesn't akcnowledge. Non-service code does so. Yes, it's called and everything is running correctly up to the `StartMonitor()` line, I tried logging there to show every single operation.

Comment: Does the documentation say anything? Maybe StartMonitor needs to be called from the main thread of the application? MayI ask why you call it from the service at all? Shouldn't that be something that is started *once*?

Comment: Old C++/C DLL of about 15 years ago, no threading, nothing like that. It's only the service that has access to this old code, so no chance to call it from anywhere else. `TestMonitor` is just what is says, a one-off short test. If it works, I might need to reorganize where it's called from inside the service, yes.

Comment: Well, without access to the code of `StartMonitor` or a very long night of assembly debugging, you are out of luck. It doesn't work. Without knowing what the code in question actually does, nobody will be able to help you.

Comment: Yes, this is close to the core of the problem. :-) However, putting the same code outside a service shows that, very likely, I'd say almost certainly, the problem is with the service not allowed to listen on that port. Hence my question whether there are any other ways to grant that access so that I can try if it helps...

Comment: "The Service" is running with the same user privileges as the underlying application. If it works in your `Main` or `OnStart`, then you will need to get the source and debug.